# How do I increase the quantity of an item already in a shopping cart?

Tags: angularjs

[image: App screenshot]

I have four items in my app. If I click `Order`, an item gets added to the card. If I click `Order` again, I want to increment the `quantity` of the item in the cart, but right now it just adds another item to the cart.

```
var app = angular.module("myMenuApp", []);

//MenuController
app.controller("MenuController", function($scope, vorders) {
  var menuitems = [
    {"code": "VG101", "name": "PalakPaneer",  "price": 300, "description": "palak paneer description"},
    {"code": "DS101", "name": "Malai Kopta",  "price": 200, "description": "Malai Kopta description"},
    {"code": "AN101", "name": "Gobi Fry",     "price": 250, "description": "Gobi Fry description"},
    {"code": "VS101", "name": "Methi Chaman", "price": 280, "description": "Methi Chaman description"}
  ];

  $scope.itemsList = menuitems;

  $scope.placeOrder = function(menuitem){
    var OrderItem = { "name":menuitem.name, "price": menuitem.price, "qty":1 };
    vorders.push(OrderItem);
  }
})


//OrderedController
app.controller("OrderedController", function($scope, vorders){
  $scope.ordereditems=vorders;

  $scope.cancelOrder = function(idx) {
    vorders.splice(idx, 1);
  }

  $scope.totalAmount = function() {
    var tot = 0;
    angular.forEach(vorders, function(c) {
      tot += (c.price * c.qty);
    })
    return tot;
  }
})

app.value("vorders", []);
```

Comment: Please explain the problem using proper sentences. Include expected behavior vs current behavior. Also this is a question and answer site...what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your `placeOrder` function is only ever adding a new item to the list of orders. You need to look for an existing item of the same name and increment its count, then only add a new item if it wasn't already present. You can do this similarly to how you implemented `totalAmount`, using `forEach`.

```
$scope.placeOrder = function(menuItem) {

  var found = false;
  // Search each ordered item for the menuItem to add
  angular.forEach(vorders, function(orderedItem) {
    if (orderedItem.name == menuItem.name) { // Found it
      found = true;
      orderedItem.qty += 1; // Add one
    }
  });

  // If we didn't find an existing order, add a new one
  if (!found) {
    var newItem = { "name": menuItem.name, "price": menuItem.price, "qty": 1 }
    vorders.push(newItem);
  }

}
```